# How do you successfully use Egit with GitHub?

Tags: eclipse, github, push, egit

There seems to be no guide out there that is still valid so I'm asking how to use Egit in Eclipse to push a project to GitHub. I followed some guides but end up with an "Specifications don't match any existing refs in source repository." error in the push dialog.

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.1 and Egit 0.9.1. It should be possible to use Egit shouldn't it? it would be great if you could give a short step by step guide to push a project with Egit successfully.

Comment: I followed the [Egit GitHub tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Github_Tutorial) exactly, and had no problems getting [my project](https://github.com/mjball/Stack-Overflow-Q-A) onto Github.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you should commit the project first onto local repository.
and then select Team->Remote->Push... to push the project onto Github.